# How to load a pdf in pdf.js from a database object (blob)?

Tags: python, pyramid, pdf.js

I am using Pyramid  framework with Zope Object Database, my pdf files are not stored anywhere physically but are present in my Database in the form of objects, and even after many days of research I am not able to find out  how can I display it using pdf.js? Please help.

Comment: I don't mean to answer my own question but anybody who's facing the same problem can solve it using `FileResponse`

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question if you know the answer and it would benefit others